# How can two quadwords be compared in fasm?

Tags: assembly, x86, fasm

I need to check that a quadword is not less than zero.

I store them in MMX registers:

```
 movq mm0, [inputNum]
 movq mm1, [zero]
```

But i can't find an instruction for comparring two qwords in mmx or sse... Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Is this 32-bit code or is this 64-bit code? Are you trying to compare a QWORD 64-bit integer with 0 or a floating point number to 0.0?

Comment: If this is 32-bit code and If `inputNum` is a 64-bit (QWORD) signed integer then to test if it is not negative all you need to do is load the upper 4 bytes of `inputNum` (`[inputNum+4]` ) into a register and test if the top most bit (bit 31) is 0 or not. If it is 0 then the value is >= 0. If it is 1 the value is negative. The top most bit of the QUADWORD is the sign bit.

Comment: I've figured it out, thanks!

Comment: [pcmpgtq](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pcmpgtq) exists but requires SSE4.2, and only supports XMM regs, not legacy MMX. But fortunately as Michael Petch points out, you only need to check the sign bit; the rest of the bits are irrelevant for this and don't need to be loaded. e.g. `test byte [inputNum+7], 0x80` sets ZF and SF to the condition you want, based on the MSB of the whole qword in memory. Or `cmp` against `0`.  Or just load both halves into 32-bit registers if you want them in regs but aren't writing 64-bit code that can simply load a qword into RAX.